# Runtime of MPI_Win_create at origin is increasing with increase in the size of the target window

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I have just started studying MPI, and am doing an experiment in which I am measuring the runtime of MPI_Win_create. I am using `mpich 3.4.1` library. In this experiment, I have two processes --- origin and target. I have the the following lines of code to measure the runtime:

```
     double startTime, endTime;
     startTime = MPI_Wtime();
     MPI_Win_create(buffer, bufferSize, sizeof(char), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, win);
     endTime = MPI_Wtime();
     double winCreateTime = endTime - startTime;
```

In my experiment, the bufferSize at the origin process (rank==0), is always zero. However, at the target process (rank==1), I am increasing the buffer size up to around 2GB. I see the following trend in the runtime MPI_Win_create at origin and target processes:

At around 100MB of bufferSize for the target process, `MPI_Win_create time = 2.21`at the origin process, and `0.001071` at the target process. At around 1GB of bufferSize for the target process, `MPI_Win_create time =  25.21`at the origin process, and `0.000894` at the target process. At around 2GB, I see that at the origin process `MPI_Win_create time = 41.580131`, and at the target process `MPI_Win_create time = 0.000999`. This trend is same  for various data sizes that I have experimented with. That is, the MPI_Win_create time is consistently higher (and increasing with data size) at the origin process than at the target process. At the target process it is much lower.

From what I understand, on calling MPI_Win_create, the corresponding process creates an RMA window which exposes the memory area at the corresponding process' address space, starting at location pointed to by `buffer` and this area is of size `bufferSize`. I am not able to understand why the runtime of MPI_Win_create increases at the origin process when bufferSize is increased at the target process. And why at the target process side the runtime of MPI_Win_create is more or less constant and very small even with increasing `bufferSize`. What is happening at the origin side that is not happening at the target side?

Comment: Please upload your test case. Besides the imbalance, the duration seems suspiciously high.

Comment: Which MPI implementation and what is your platform?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I think I know the reason for this imbalance now. MPI_Win_create seems to be a collective function call in which all processes in the communicator communicate and create an MPI window. So, any process that reach this function call seems to be blocked for other participating processes to also reach this point in their respective code (correct??). In my case, the target process is generating a huge data before its call to MPI_Win_create. However, the origin does very little work before this point. So for origin, the point of startTime is arrived much earlier than in Target.

Comment: So, my  ```endTime - startTime``` at the origin also seems to include the data generation time at the target process, since it needs to wait for the target process to complete the data generation and reach its corresponding MPI_Win_create. However, the target side,  ```endTime - startTime```  seems to be the actual time the target spends on its MPI_Win_create.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I am using mpich 3.4.1 implementation on CentOS 7.7.1908 (x86_64)

Comment: This is one of the reason I asked you to provide your test case: lack of synchronization (e.g. `MPI_Barrier()`) can result in your timers measuring load imbalance instead of window creation.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you. I see reasonable runtimes on using MPI_Barrier(), as I have posted in my answer below. I have another question: at the origin process, can I also get the size of a certain target process' window through MPI_Win object pointer that is passed to  MPI_Win_create? or in any other manner without passing msg again? I did not get this information so far on searching.

Comment: generally speaking no. But if you `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()`, you can `MPI_Win_shared_query()`

Comment: Ok. I thought since the processes in the comm communicates among themselves during window creation, it would not be difficult to store the various process' window size info (may be in an object like MPI_win) and pass it back to the processes (only on occasions that the user so desires, as I understand it could be huge data if there are hundreds of processes in the comm). Of course, win free has to be taken care of too.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to my own question. After digging deeper, I found the reason for the imbalance in runtimes between origin and target process was due to the lack of synchronization before measuring the start time.

MPI_Win_create is a  collective function call in which all processes in the communicator communicate and create an MPI window. So, any process that reaches this function call seems to be blocked for other participating processes to also reach this point in their respective code. In my case, the target process is generating a huge data before its call to MPI_Win_create. However, the origin does very little work before this point. So for origin, the point of `startTime` is arrived much earlier than in Target. As a result, my `endTime - startTime` at the origin process also includes the data generation time at the target process, since it needs to wait for the target process to complete the data generation and reach its corresponding MPI_Win_create. However, at the target side, `endTime - startTime` is the actual time the target spends on its MPI_Win_create.

Solution: I am able to get reasonable runtimes on using MPI_Barrier() just before the point at which I measure the startTime, as shown in the following model code snippet.
With this change, for buffer size of around 2GB, I am getting the MPI_Win_create runtime at the origin process of around 0.000347 sec and at the target process of around 0.000382 sec.

```
#include <mpi.h>

#define ORIGIN 0
#define TARGET 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    double startTime, endTime;

    char *buffer = nullptr;
    long bufferSize = 0;
    if (my_rank == TARGET) {
        bufferSize = 2000000000;
        buffer = new char[bufferSize](); //OR, getLargeData()
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Win window;

    startTime = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Win_create(buffer, bufferSize, sizeof(char), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &window);

    endTime = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);

    printf("\nMPI_Win_create time at %s = %lf", (my_rank == ORIGIN)?"ORIGIN":"TARGET", endTime-startTime);

    MPI_Win_free(&window);

    if (buffer) delete[] buffer;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Interesting scenario. Yes, barriers before and after the thing you're timing is usualy a good idea.